# How to Queue or Pipeline Many Flex Animations?

Tags: apache-flex, performance, animation, effects, transition

I have a Flex application where some interactions cause many objects to require visual updates all at once. These updates translate into state changes for many MXML based components which have state based transitions. The transitions look great when just a handful of the components animate at the same time... but when all of them animate at once... the Flash Player just can't keep up.

Any ideas on how to create something of an animation pipeline so that everything can have a chance to keep up? Or maybe some other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try working with `suspendBackgroundProcessing` property of `Effect` or `disableLayout` property of `Animate` class descendants? You can define them on MXML animation definition nodes.

Comment: Just tried it... but still doesn't work smooth at all. Seems like such a simple thing. I really like the syntax for adding transitions... but its just not cutting it. Also, I have filters and sorts enabled on my lists and the item renderers continually get reshuffled (if there is a difference between states during the reshuffle lots of unsightly animations trigger).

Comment: You can call `disableAutoUpdate()` for a while and then `enableAutoUpdate()` on the `dataProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I try to stay away from the Adobe effects library as they're slow and not all that good.  If you want animation 'groupings', consecutive animations, or even animation timelines, I would suggest you use [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/).

Comment: I've used tweenmax and tweenlite before... I was hoping not to have to resort to programatic animations... I'll give it a try.